# How to use shared libraries with JenkinsPipelineUnit from current branch

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-pipeline-unit

I'm trying to use jenkinsPipelineUnit to test a JenkinsFile that exists in the same git repository as my shared libraries. This Jenkinsfile references shared libraries located in src. It appears that I must commit my shared library changes before I can test them even if I use localSource from within the retriever.

How can I load my shared libraries and unit test them without committing the code first?

Here is my current code that doesn't work:

```groovy
    def library = library().name('pipeline-utils')
            .defaultVersion("master")
            .allowOverride(true)
            .implicit(false)
            .targetPath(sharedLibs)
            .retriever(localSource(sharedLibs))
            .build()
    helper.registerSharedLibrary(library)

    try {
         def script = runScript("pipelines/test.groovy")
    }
```

I get this error:

```
    file:/Users/<myuserid>/git/pipelines/test.groovy: 2: 
    Error on loading library pipeline-utils@myteam/pipelineUnitTest : 
    Directory /Users/<myuserid>/git/out/test/classes/com/company/test/pipeline-utils@myteam/pipelineUnitTest does not exists @ line 2, column 1. 
    @Library("pipeline-utils@myteam/pipelineUnitTest") _
```

Comment: This sounds kind of like [JenkinsPipelineUnit/75](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/pull/75) and [JenkinsPipelineUnit/64](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/pull/64).

Comment: Thanks! Those two pull requests address exactly what I'm trying to achieve: direct testing of shared libraries. So the current answer to my question could be "not currently supported". However I'm wondering if someone could recommend a way to leverage the PipelineTestHelper class directly...this seems to be where the magic happens of injecting the allowed methods. Maybe the answer is in the details of one of those pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as easy as it sounds. JenkinsPipelineUnit isn't moving any more since one year while some interesting work is waiting on pull-requests. Here are the steps I had to go through to get this working locally, but also on jenkins where the name of my repository directory can be different each time.

## 1. Create a custom version of JenkinsPipelineUnit

I started from https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/pull/75 but had to add some other changes. These are all the changes:

```
diff --git a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryConfiguration.groovy b/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryConfiguration.groovy
index f4eeb17..dc13b9c 100644
--- a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryConfiguration.groovy
+++ b/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryConfiguration.groovy
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@ class LibraryConfiguration {
     String targetPath

     LibraryConfiguration validate() {
-        if (name && defaultVersion && retriever && targetPath)
+        if (name && retriever && targetPath && ((retriever instanceof LocalSource || defaultVersion)))
             return this
         throw new IllegalStateException("LibraryConfiguration is not properly initialized ${this.toString()}")
     }
diff --git a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryLoader.groovy b/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryLoader.groovy
index 120a316..a253f2d 100644
--- a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryLoader.groovy
+++ b/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LibraryLoader.groovy
@@ -117,11 +117,14 @@ class LibraryLoader {
     }

     private static boolean matches(String libName, String version, LibraryConfiguration libraryDescription) {
+        if (libraryDescription.allowOverride) {
+            return true
+        }
         if (libraryDescription.name == libName) {
             if (version == null) {
                 return true
             }
-            if (libraryDescription.allowOverride || libraryDescription.defaultVersion == version) {
+            if (libraryDescription.defaultVersion == version) {
                 return true
             }
         }
diff --git a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LocalSource.groovy b/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LocalSource.groovy
index 61babde..4edca23 100644
--- a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LocalSource.groovy
+++ b/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/global/lib/LocalSource.groovy
@@ -11,7 +11,13 @@ class LocalSource implements SourceRetriever {

     @Override
     List<URL> retrieve(String repository, String branch, String targetPath) {
-        def sourceDir = new File(sourceURL).toPath().resolve("$repository@$branch").toFile()
+        def sourceURLPath = new File(sourceURL).toPath()
+        def sourceDir
+        if (branch) {
+            sourceDir = sourceURLPath.resolve("$repository@$branch").toFile()
+        } else {
+            sourceDir = sourceURLPath.resolve(repository).toFile()
+        }
         if (sourceDir.exists()) {
             return [sourceDir.toURI().toURL()]
         }
```

## 2. Register your current repository directory as your shared library

Inspired from: https://github.com/jimcroft/jenkinslib-example/blob/master/test/com/example/TestCase1.groovy

in your TestClass.groovy:

```
void setup() {
    String repositoryDirectoryName = FilenameUtils.getName(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
    String dirPath = new File( System.getProperty("user.dir") )
            .getAbsoluteFile()
            .getParentFile()
            .getAbsolutePath()

    // This next call bypasses registerSharedLibrary; to allow registering a library with a different directory name
    helper.libraries.put('my-jenkins-library', library(repositoryDirectoryName)
                    .allowOverride(true)
                    .implicit(false)
                    .targetPath(dirPath)
                    .retriever(localSource(dirPath))
                    .build())
```